# What is the difference?

Tags: python

What is the difference between writing the method like this:

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=60):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
```

and this:

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = 60
```

In both cases, if we don't assign the value of battery_size, Python will use the default value, which is 60. Both are working properly but I just want to know the difference just to clear my concepts.

Comment: The difference is in the second one there's no way to supply any _other_ value.

Comment: In the first one, the constructor can _optionally_ take an argument: `battery = Battery(120)`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
def __init__(self, battery_size=60):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
```

And

```
def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = 60
```

In the first one, `def __init__(self, battery_size=60):`, `battery_size` is a parameter. `=60` shows that the default value of `battery_size` is 60.

So if you instantiate the class:

```
x=Battery()
```

No error will be raised even though there is a parameter. This is because you have told python to take the value of `battery_size` as 60 whenever a value **is not** provided.
But if you call the function like this:

```
x=Battery(75)
```

The value of `battery_size` is now 75. This is assigned to `self.battery_size`

---

In the second example:

```
self.battery_size=60
```

Here, it is already defined. So whatever you do, `self.battery_size` will always remain 60 unless you do something to it like add, subtract, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Battery():
    def __init__(self):
        self.battery_size = 60
b = Battery(40) # here you cannot pass arguments into the class.
#it will return error as `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
```

Instead you can try with above class as follows,

```
b = Battery()
print(b.battery_size) # Output is 60
```

Second example

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=60):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
b = Battery(999999)
print(b.battery_size) # Here i didn't get any error and o/p is 999999
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=60):
        """Initialize the battery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
```

Here the `battery_size` has a default value of 60.

You can create `Battery` objects with varying `battery_size` with this method. See example below

```
# Creating a Battery object without passing any battery_size parameter
A = Battery()
print(A.battery_size)           #Prints 60 because the default value is 60

# Creating a Battery object by passing a value = 90 for battery_size
B = Battery(90)
print(B.battery_size)           #Prints 90
```

**Second method:**

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = 60
```

With the second method you **cannot** pass any values for `battery_size`. All objects by default will have the `battery_size` as 60.

You cannot create object `B` like in the above with second method.

**In short**

- If you want to create  `Battery` objects where all objects have a constant `battery_size` as 60 - **Go with second method.**
- If you want to create `Battery` objects with different `battery_size` - **Go with first method.**